# c# MariaDB error MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of data packet

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mariadb

even though the connection string is ok as far as i know, it seems like it cannot gather the information that requires.
The account is local and all of the tables/databases have been created. I simply dont know where the error is.
ive tried changing the connection string like 5 times and nothing has improoved

the exception presented : `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of data packet`

```
 private async Task LoopingActions()
 {
        string command = "SELECT * FROM `data`.`messages` LIMIT 1;";
   //uso un archivo yml para la configuracion del cliente -- i use a yml file for the config of the client
        var _connection = new MySqlConnection($"server={_config["SQLConnection:Server"]}; database={_config["SQLConnection:Database"]}; port={_config["SQLConnection:Port"]}; user={_config["SQLConnection:UserId"]}; pwd={_config["SQLConnection:Password"]}; ");
    try
    {
        _connection.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

    var Addtabletest = new MySqlCommand(command,_connection);

    try
    {
      MySqlDataReader test = Addtabletest.ExecuteReader();  
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine(ex); 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("test");
            
  }
```

edit:
i think i figured it out, the  problem is the `SELECT *`   i can get the individual or all of the fields i need but only if i name them

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your issue, but you *must* dispose your connection, command and reader with `using`, do *not* cache them. I would also posit that there' not much point calling the database if you don;t actually do anything with the data: I would expect a loop of the reader, or a load into a datatable etc

Comment: It's possible that MySql.Data has some incompatibilities with MariaDB. To test that, you could switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (disclaimer: lead author) which is regularly tested against multiple versions of MariaDB and has good support for it.

Comment: Please supply the full exception details in your question: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/